# URL Rewrite Rule is not working after changing the pagename

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have wordpress site and I want to make my service page to have states specific URL's. For that I have duplicated my service page and changed the content to state specific using the shortcode.

And I did URL rewrite Rule to get state specific URL for my service page. Below is the rule I have it for my service Page to get state specific page. This rewrite rule is working fine and I got all state based URL.

function mp_rewrite(){
add_rewrite_rule('^(my-service-page)-([^/]*)/?', 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&usstate=$matches[2]','top');

```
     }
```

This is my service page URL look like: **example.com/service-page**

When it is comes to state specific it looks like: **example.com/service-page-new-york**

The only problem which I'm facing is, when I change the title of the page, the rewrite rule is not working and I can't able to get state based URL and it is redirecting back to my service page. I want to know why it is redirecting to my service page instead of showing state URL.

How to resolve it.